# Session variable not storing the selected drop down value

Tags: php

I am trying to store a selected drop down value in session variable and every time i print that variable which i am using on other page it shows me the last value of array from which i am populating my drop down basically.
here is the code;

```
<?php $options = array('2CHECKOUT','PAYPAL'); ?>

<select name="payment" style="width:225px;" id ="mySelect">
    <?php foreach($options as $opt) { ?>
        <?php $selected = (isset($_SESSION['payment']) && $opt == $_SESSION['payment']) ? ' SELECTED' : '';
        echo '<option value="'.$opt.'"' .$selected.'>'.$opt.'</option>'; ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php error_log("the session var".print_r($_SESSION['payment'])); ?>
</select> </div>
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: how are you storing the data in SESSION

Comment: What are the results of `$_SESSION['payment']` and `print_r($options)`?

Comment: Do I need to store data in session variable? or will selected value automatically get populated when I do `$someVar = $_SESSION['payment']` on the pages I need?

Comment: `$_SESSION['payment']` would always give me 2CHECKOUT and `print_r($options)` is `Array ( [0] => 2CHECKOUT [1] => PAYPAL )`

Comment: @user2067888 No PHP is not magical and won't set the data in a session variable. You need to do something like `$_SESSION['payment'] = 'myData'` and `echo $_SESSION['payment'] //output: myData`

Comment: where you storing data in session?

Answer (score -1):

change your code as

```
<?php $options = array('2CHECKOUT','PAYPAL'); ?>

<div>
<select name="payment" style="width:225px;" id ="mySelect">
    <?php foreach($options as $opt) { ?>
        <?php $selected = (isset($_SESSION['payment']) && $opt == $_SESSION['payment']) ? ' SELECTED' : '';
        echo '<option value="'.$opt.'"' .$selected.'>'.$opt.'</option>'; ?>
    <?php } ?>

</select> 
<?php error_log("the session var".print_r($_SESSION['payment'])); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, have you added `<div>` tag? if so, sorry i didn't paste the `div` tag. I already have it in my code. Any other idea?

Comment: you are printing $_SESSION value inside the select tag

Comment: have you stored session any where?